# How to reset google recaptcha in contact form 7 after every submit

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha, contact-form-7

I have created a contact form through contact form 7. i add google recaptcha v2 by using captcha them all plugin. It won't refreshes on submits and if there is validation it show Captcha validation fails

Comment: You mean, after validation failed and form was not submitted at all ? still you want to refresh captcha ?

Comment: I got it working by                                                                                      
                           <script> var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );
wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7invalid', function( event ) {
       grecaptcha.reset(); }, false );</script>